# Como faco uma mascara para um input?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar máscara de *CPF* em um `input`, já vi várias respostas aqui e nenhuma deu certo, tentei usar o `mask` no próprio `input`, no *jQuery* e nenhum deu certo.

Eu uso a *Framework Materialize*. Será que isso que está retornando esse erro?

Comment: Compartilhe conosco o que esteve tentando

Answer (score 23):

Você pode fazer também com JavaScript puro!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Máscara CPF</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function fMasc(objeto,mascara) {
    obj=objeto
    masc=mascara
    setTimeout("fMascEx()",1)
   }
   function fMascEx() {
    obj.value=masc(obj.value)
   }
   function mTel(tel) {
    tel=tel.replace(/\D/g,"")
    tel=tel.replace(/^(\d)/,"($1")
    tel=tel.replace(/(.{3})(\d)/,"$1)$2")
    if(tel.length == 9) {
     tel=tel.replace(/(.{1})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 10) {
     tel=tel.replace(/(.{2})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 11) {
     tel=tel.replace(/(.{3})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 12) {
     tel=tel.replace(/(.{4})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length > 12) {
     tel=tel.replace(/(.{4})$/,"-$1")
    }
    return tel;
   }
   function mCNPJ(cnpj){
    cnpj=cnpj.replace(/\D/g,"")
    cnpj=cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
    cnpj=cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2.$3")
    cnpj=cnpj.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/,".$1/$2")
    cnpj=cnpj.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1-$2")
    return cnpj
   }
   function mCPF(cpf){
    cpf=cpf.replace(/\D/g,"")
    cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
    cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
    cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")
    return cpf
   }
   function mCEP(cep){
    cep=cep.replace(/\D/g,"")
    cep=cep.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
    cep=cep.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/,".$1-$2")
    return cep
   }
   function mNum(num){
    num=num.replace(/\D/g,"")
    return num
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <input type="text" name="cpf" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );">

 </body>
</html>
```

Já deixei pronto algumas máscaras: CNPJ, CEP, telefone e somente números.

Essas máscaras foram desenvolvidas baseadas em expressões regulares. Vale a pena estudar sobre o assunto.

Comment: Perfeito amigo. A vantagem dessa sua máscara é que ele pode ser utilizada em validações via AJAX/SQL pois não é submetida, contrário do Jquery Mask.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca do *jQuery Mask*:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Com ela você consegue aplicar vários tipos de máscara.

Basta *linkar* a biblioteca no seu `html`: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.min.js`

Para *CPF* você deve fazer dessa forma:

```
$('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
```