# Erro na máscara de CPF

Tags: javascript, html5

Criei um formulário porém quando fui pôr máscara no CPF para ficar assim Ex.(000.000.000-00) não atribui

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JS/funcoes.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery-Mask-Plugin-master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```js
if(event.keyCode !== 8){
        if(texto.length === 3 || texto.length === 7){
            document.getElementById("cpf").value == texto + ".";
        } else if(texto.length === 11){
            document.getElementById("cpf").value == texto + "-";
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="salvarregistro.php" method="POST">
            
 <input type="text" name="cpf" size="40" id="cpf" required="" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx" onkeyup="mascCPF(this.value)"><br><br>
            
            <button type="submit">Enviar dados</button>
            
            
        </form>
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199264/57801

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pro seu código você pode tentar assim:

```js
function mascCPF(texto) {
  if(event.keyCode != 8) {
    if(texto.length === 3 || texto.length === 7) {
        document.getElementById("cpf").value = texto + ".";
    } else if(texto.length === 11){
        document.getElementById("cpf").value = texto + "-";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="salvarregistro.php" method="POST">
            
 <input type="text" name="cpf" size="40" maxlength="14" id="cpf" required="" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx" onkeydown="mascCPF(this.value)"><br><br>
            
            <button type="submit">Enviar dados</button>
            
            
        </form>
```

Mas eu recomendo você usar uma biblioteca para fazer isso, te indico essa: [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

EDIT:

Com o jQuery-Mask-Plugin:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('#cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<form action="salvarregistro.php" method="POST">
            
 <input type="text" name="cpf" size="40" id="cpf" required="" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx"><br><br>
            
    <button type="submit">Enviar dados</button>


</form>
```

Comment: Não deu certo, eu coloquei o trecho das bibliotecas para auxiliar na resposta

Comment: @RuanRodrigues editei a resposta, e coloquei um exemplo com o plugin!

Comment: Esse trecho aqui - window.onload = function() {
  $('#cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
} - eu insiro no meu arquivo.js?

Comment: Sim, senhor!!!!

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma também para ajudar, se estiver utilizando bootstrap, basta fazer de uma forma bem simples. Mas para funcionar deve ter importada a biblioteca jQuery.mask

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
        $('#rg').mask('00.000.000-0');
    });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12">                             
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <label for="ex1">CPF:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" maxlength="11"  name="cpf" placeholder='___.___.___-__'><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">  
  <div class="col-lg-5">
       <label for="ex1">RG:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" maxlength="9"  name="rg" placeholder='__.___.___-_'><br>
  </div>
</div>
```