# Input automatico

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou desenvolvendo uma pagina de login com cpf e senha, fiz varias pesquisas e não cheguei a nenhuma conclusão de como colocar os sinais automático, por exemplo... No input : Cpf quando eu digita o numero ir para a ordem jogando o ###.###.###-## 
No caso os (..-).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        .corTitulo{
            color: #286090;
            font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form" class="form-signin">       
           <h1 class="form-signin-heading corTitulo">LOGIN</h1>
              <hr class="colorgraph"><br>            
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Digite seu cpf..." required autofocus />
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Digite sua senha..." required>            
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Entrar</button>
              <br>      
              <a class="cora" href="TrocarSenha.php">Esqueici minha senha?</a>      
        </form>         
    </div>
< /div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso deve resolver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199264/como-faco-uma-mascara-para-um-input/199276#199276

Comment: Pode experimentar também o https://github.com/vanilla-masker/vanilla-masker que é um lib JS interessante.