# Máscara de entrada para CPF no formulário html (sem plugin)

Tags: javascript, html

Eu queria uma máscara de entrada simples, apenas para colocar 999.999.999-99, pontos e o ultimo traço no campo de cpf, sem verificação, sem nada, simples, e sem plugin apenas código, se não me engano tem a regrex ou algo similar, agradeço a atenção!

Comment: dá uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199264/como-faco-uma-mascara-para-um-input

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar este, mas só funciona com `blur`:

```js
var cpf = document.querySelector("#cpf");

cpf.addEventListener("blur", function(){
   if(cpf.value) cpf.value = cpf.value.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".").replace(/\.(?=[^.]*$)/,"-");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf" maxlength="11" />
```

---

Tem este também que funciona enquanto o CPF está sendo digitado:

```js
function mascara(i){
   
   var v = i.value;
   
   if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){ // impede entrar outro caractere que não seja número
      i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
      return;
   }
   
   i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
   if (v.length == 3 || v.length == 7) i.value += ".";
   if (v.length == 11) i.value += "-";

}
```

```html
<input oninput="mascara(this)" type="text">
```

Comment: Obrigado! ambos funcionam certinho!

Comment: Fiz uma pequena correção no primeiro. Abs!